# only last chunk is read though written many chunk of data using core bluetooth ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am writing data `"hi.. hello"` divided it in to chunks of 1 byte using `write value` method to peripheral which calls

1. `did write method` in which i am calling
2. `set notify` which calls
3. `update notification` within which i am calling
4. `read value for characteristics` which calls delegate method
5. `did update value for characterisitics` where i want to get written value back.

When i am going this way i am getting only last chunk of data not whole string/data.
please help me and guide me where i am wrong so that i could resolve it. thanks in advance